# Opening a google drive file using the google drive api while I'm NOT signed in to google drive

Tags: node.js, sails.js, orientdb, google-drive-api

This has really been bugging me for some time so any help to confirm or affirm this is much appreciated! This is also the first time I actually post a question despite being developing for a long time :)

So I have a nodejs app integrating with the Google Drive API and I want users to authorize multiple Google Drive accounts and be able to view and open (and in general just interact with) all files from the accounts that they add.

I authorize my app using the highest available scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and because I don't want users to have to sign-in again when the access_token runs out so I also include the `approval_prompt: "force"` and ``access_type: "offline"` when I request my access tokens.

Everything is fine - I authorize nicely, I can delete files, I can open them, I can share them, I can download them. Except for one thing:
If I e.g. authorize horse@gmail.com and then beaver@gmail.com. Then I can still delete, share, download and preview files from **both accounts**. But I simply **cannot open** documents from **horse@gmail.com** in google docs for editing (because beaver@gmail.com is signed in on my local machine). The best I can do is getting to a point where it shows me the document, with the right account logged in in the top right corner of the screen, but asks me to sign-in with a button. When I click the button it just refreshes and give me the same message and the same screen.

What I've tried is:

1. Simply redirecting the user to the file resources `alternateLink` from the API
2. Taking the `alternateLink` and appending my `access_token` to it and then redirect the user to it.
   (and a ton of other random things I found various places that didn't work).

In both cases I have also tried signing out from all google accounts.

Now I checked a couple of webservices like Jollicloud and Odrive that tries something similar. However, both of them appear to force the user to login to google to access a file.

Is it really true that you can do all kinds of crazy things with the users files like deleting and downloading, but you can't open them in Google Docs own apps?

Not completely sure what kind of code I should add to show you what I've got. But here's some. This is my open action (what happens when the user clicks on a file and wants to open the file in the Google Docs/Sheet/etc.) (the orientdb stuff is because we're using the OrientDB graph database - it just fetches an account where we store the tokens). The link is the link property of the file (see below):

```
open: function(req,res,next){
    var link = req.param("link");
    var uid = req.param("uid");
    orientdb.select().from('Account').where({uid: uid}).one()
    .then(function(account){
        var URL = link + "&access_token=" + account.tokens.access_token;
        res.redirect(URL);
    });
}
```

Here's an example file document from our database (I've replaced all compromising data with a descriptive

### ODocument - Class: File   id: #13:20499   v.6

```
            name : Hummer2             
         service : Gdrive              
            kind : Google Doc          
         created : Nov 17, 2014        
         changed : Nov 17, 2014        
           users : [MB]                
             uid : mrb@flowtale.com    
         childID : <FILE.ID>
     exportLinks : {DOCX=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<FILE.ID>&exportFormat=docx, Open Office doc=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<FILE.ID>&exportFormat=odt, Rich text=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<FILE.ID>&exportFormat=rtf, HTML=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<FILE.ID>&exportFormat=html, Plain text=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<FILE.ID>&exportFormat=txt, PDF=https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=<FILE.ID>&exportFormat=pdf}
       usernames : [<ARRAY OF USERNAMES ASSOCIATED WITH THIS FILE>]
      in_hasFile : User#11:0{out_hasFile:[size=2237],out_hasAccount:[size=4],username:null,email:h@h.com,password:<SOME ENCRYPTED PASSWORD>} v2244
   out_belongsTo : Account#12:3{in_belongsTo:[size=6],type:Gdrive,uid:<SOME UID>,tokens:{access_token=<OUR ACCOUNT ACCESS TOKEN>, token_type=Bearer, refresh_token=<OUR ACCOUNT REFRESH TOKEN>, expiry_date=1416258913290},rootFolderID:<ROOT FOLDER ID>,email:<THE ACCOUNT EMAIL>,filesCached:2,usersCached:2,job:4,in_hasAccount:#11:0} v15

in_folderContains : File#13:20495{out_folderContains:[size=2],name:Testhest,service:Gdrive,kind:folder,created:Oct 12, 2014,changed:Oct 12, 2014,users:[1],link:https://docs.google.com/a/flowtale.com/folderview?id=<FOLDER.ID>&usp=drivesdk,uid:mrb@flowtale.com,childID:<FOLDER.ID>,exportLinks:{},usernames:[1],parents:[1],in_hasFile:#11:0,out_belongsTo:#12:3,in_folderContains:#13:13891} v36
            link : https://docs.google.com/a/flowtale.com/document/d/<FILE.ID>/edit?usp=drivesdk
```

Looking forward to hear if anybody can help me or have experienced this before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The API will allow you to do several actions in your drive account. I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior you mention with files that I haven't granted permissions to another account.

When you authenticate through the OAuth process, you will grant access to your account only to the application which created the OAuth request. You can not edit the content of a file without manually opening it through GDocs. Therefore, when the browser opens the AlternateUrl, it will require you to login to the account, in order to access the file.